# deep nested attributes and attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

With the params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"mZ0yUwkdUhi8JVeXfPPzukYr8QfmJjC0UptG3rS08Fo=",
 "commit"=>"Update Artist",
 "artist"=>{"name"=>"Test",
 "bio"=>"Some bio",
 "city"=>"Chicago",
 "state"=>"IL",
 "visible"=>"1",
 "published_at"=>"2013-06-05 20:23:48 UTC",
 "confirmed_at"=>"2013-06-05 12:00:00 UTC",
 "galleries_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"media_items_attributes"=>{"1370495729379"=>{"_destroy"=>"0",
 "mediable_type"=>"Image",
 "mediable_id"=>"45"}}}}},
 "id"=>"test"}
```

I have the following in my attr_accesible on my artist model

`attr_accessible :media_items_attributes, :galleries_attributes, :name, :bio, :permalink, :billboard_image_id, :featured_at, :city, :state, :country, :latitude, :longitude, :visible, :confirmed_at, :published_at, :deleted_at, :genre_ids, as: :admin`

but i still get an exception

`Can't mass-assign protected attributes: media_items_attributes`

I have the following in my gallery model

`attr_accessible :media_items_attributes`

i am puzzled.

where do i need to allow `:media_items_attributes` ?

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :galeryable
  attr_accessible :media_items_attributes
  has_many :media_items, :as => :mediable


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :media_items

end


class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base


# Basic attibutes, associations and validations
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  attr_accessible :media_items_attributes, :galleries_attributes, :name, :bio, :permalink, :billboard_image_id, :featured_at, :city, :state, :country, :latitude, :longitude, :visible, :confirmed_at, :published_at, :deleted_at, :genre_ids, as: :admin

  # Validations
  validates_presence_of :name, :bio, :city, :state
  validate :publishable

  # Geocode the artist based on city and state
  geocoded_by :city_state
    after_validation :geocode

  has_many :genrefications, as: :genreable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :genres, through: :genrefications
  has_many :galleries, as: :galleryable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :galleries

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess: in the Gallery model.

From the look of your nested hash - the media_items_attributes comes under the gallery_attributes section. So you need to put it at that level.

Comment: i added it to the gallery model.

Comment: Also do you have "accepts_nested_attributes" for all those nested attributes?

Comment: i feel like im missing a syntax in my artist model

Comment: so the first thing to check would be: does it all work if you have no attr_accessible at all (ie that verifies that the syntax, nesting and structure is correct).

Comment: the :as => :admin i need that in gallery too! i figured it would default to the genric but it does not.

Comment: :) awesome. "I am an idiot" problems are generally the easiest to fix (once spotted) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Though your problem is solved I am replying this for others to get clear idea:

Here is a typical scenario:

if the model definitions are like as follows:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :name, :posts_attributes
  has_many :posts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
end
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content :user_id
end
```

then everything should be fine. You can save user with posts as nested attributes.

Here is a sample project containing this scenario:

https://github.com/railscash/sample_change_user_role

Comment: my issue was more-so that post also accepted attributes for say "comments"

Comment: if post, adding comments_attributes in attr_accessible and accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments should be enough